# Comparing coordinates of a point in different orthophotos

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have a orthophoto in EPSG:5972 which I consider to be "the truth".
According to QGIS, EPSG:5972 is:
"Based on European Terrestrial Reference System 1989 ensemble (EPSG:6258), which has a limited accuracy of at best 0.1 meters".
So I am assuming/hoping that the orthophoto is correct down to 10 cm.

Next I have another orthophoto of the same area generated in-house in EPSG:32632.
The output coordinate system of the generation of this orthophoto can be changed.

I want to compare the latter orthophoto, in QGIS, with the first orthophoto ("the truth").

Acoording to QGIS, EPSG:32632 is: "
Based on World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble (EPSG:6326), which has a limited accuracy of at best 2 meters".

Is generating the second orthophoto in EPSG:32632 a mistake?

I would think it should be generated in EPSG:5972 as well?

If I read the coordinates of the same point in both orthophotos and compare them how large can the error be? 10 cm? 20 cm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first assumption is incorrect. The accuracy statement refers to the coordinate reference system (CRS) itself. ETRS89 has had several versions (also called realizations or re-adjustments) over the years. If a dataset says it's using ETRS89, it could actually be referenced to any one of several possible ETRS89 re-adjustments, thus the statement that **at best** you state an accuracy of 0.1 m unless there's a separate data accuracy statement which includes information about which ETRS89 re-adjustment is being used.

The data itself could have much worse accuracy because of how it was collected/compiled.

The same problem exists with "WGS 84". It has also had multiple realizations over the years and saying something is "WGS 84" is just not enough information any more. If you try to overlay WGS 84 data with other WGS 84 data they could actually be using different realizations which might differ by up to 2 meters.

The second orthophoto should use whatever coordinate reference system is its native CRS--what was used for geodetic control of the data? Then you can reproject it to ETRS89 which will give you a better idea of what the resulting accuracy may be because the transformation you use should have a general accuracy statement.